# page not found ajax error 404 calling php url

Tags: php, ajax, call

i have a folder who has all of my code, css html js and php, all in their respective folders (index is not on any folder, php is on folder called php, css is on folder called css, js is on folder called js). So i am trying to create a log in menu where i can create new accounts and connect to a sql db. The problem is it tells me that it cannot find the folder containing this code (login.php) from an ajax call in jquery. My code is the following for further understanding:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitUserForm").click(function(){
        var nombre = $("#user").val();
        var password = $("#pass").val();
        var dataString = 'name1=' + nombre+ '&password=' +password;
        if(nombre=="" | password == ""){
            alert("Ha dejado campos vacíos");

        }else{

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../php/login.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: false,

            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

I have also tried changing the file to the folder where the js is but i cant get it to work, and calling it with url: "login.php". This is my log in code:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "myUser", "myPass"); 
        $db = mysql_select_db("mydba", $connection); 

        $name1 = $_POST["user"];
        $pass1 = $_POST["pass"];


        $query = mysql_query("insert into form_element(userName, userPassword) values($name, $pass)");
        //header("Location:../inicio.html");
        mysql_close($connection);
    ?>
```

Can u help me make this ajax call work? thank you very much!

Comment: try with one period like this `url: "./php/login.php",`

Comment: well, the error is gone, but it does not direct me to that page (ive added an echo/alert to see if it goes there and it doesnt) any ideas? @MichaelDoye

Comment: are you using `header("Location:../inicio.html");` for the redirect?

Comment: No, i mean, i want it to go to the php url, and it does not lol... im not inserting anything in the db cause it dooes not go to login.php